# Empty suggested edit?

Tags: bug, estado-completado, colas-de-revisión

I just reviewed a suggested edit that consisted in nothing:

In https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12155:

[image]

we see no split view to distinguish the changes, like all suggested edits have. [See one for example](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12128):

[image]

Comment: The comment says that "it's a translation request". As if they were to flag that question. Weird way to do this. Anyway, when I only type in a comment but do not change anything, the change "Save Edits" doesn't result into an error message but doesn't save it as a change, either. Though, I'm wondering what would happen if I make a change, save it, and then undo the change by hand (e.g. pasting the original text). As long as an edit is not approved/rejected, you can still edit that one.

Comment: @Em1 exactly, I also did the test to edit without any change and the tooltip said _Nothing appears to have changed_. Could you test it so we can see if this is the case?

Comment: So, I've tried to fake-edit one of your posts and I also get that tooltip. I didn't get that tooltip when I made a fake-edit on the German sister site where I have enough reputation for edits. Just tried it again. The edit appears to be accepted and, though, no edit was saved.

Comment: @Em1 thanks a lot. Note the [user PERCE-NEIGE](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/9086/perce-neige) has reputation 101 in this site, so it would match your first attempt.

Comment: One theory about that change, though. Certain changes aren't highlighted. For example, when you add or remove a line break that doesn't affect the post. (E.g. 5 line breaks in a row are rendered to a single line break.) This particular example, however, is not considered a change by the system. I tried to insert a couple of meaningless line breaks to a post of yours, and a tooltip tells me that I have to make more edits. With that being said, there might be some kind of negligible change that doesn't get rendered but is considered a real change by the system.

Comment: I found a releavant discussion: [Edit Review shows only comment and no changes to the post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261042/1983854). It can be related t othe grace period, as you said, and also with some rebaking of `...` and things like that.

Comment: What happened is that a tag with an accent was suggested: [tag:traducción]. Reported in [Diff highlighting fails on tags with diacritics in suggested edits reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297660/209901)

Comment: So, post it as an answer. The comment won't be read by anyone.

Comment: @Em1 good point, I added an answer. Let's see if SE employees notice this and we get a solution.

Comment: @Em1 I see this was solved somewhere in the past. No news in Meta.SE about the solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in time this was resolved, so this works well now. See how the tag is highlighted in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12155

> [image]

---

As indicated in [Diff highlighting fails on tags with diacritics in suggested edits reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297660/diff-highlighting-fails-on-tags-with-diacritics-in-suggested-edits-reviews) , this is a bug on edit suggestions affecting those tags that contain accents.

So in this case the tag [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n) was proposed to be added but no highlight was shown.

Let's see if it gets solved in any of the places where it has been reported.